# Are there deployed template smart contracts

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment

I noticed that a lot of code is reused between smart contracts,so are there any template erc747 or erc20 contracts that we could use delegate call on to avoid unnecessary usage of storage.
I think it would be worth it despite the complications using delegate call would lead to and could make deploying smart contracts more accessible for small devs.

EDIT: For example instead of importing the commonly used ownable.sol contract and wasting storage/money,can't we just deploy it only once on the network and access it from other smart contracts that don't have the ownable.sol code (I know this is a bad example since ownable is a very short contract but I think for most erc20 tokens there are like at least 200 identical lines of code)

Answer (score 1):

yes there are, [dapp.tools](https://dapp.tools/) and [openzeppelin](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/) being the most battle tested and reused

Comment: Can you please give me some example where this is used I didn't find any (just to be sure we are talking about the same thing,I know that openzeppelin has a list of commonly used contracts, for example ownable.sol,but I was meaning instead of wasting storage and money by importing everytime ownable.sol can't we just deploy it only once on the network and have every contract plugging into it somehow.